# Scrollview setcontentsize for dynamic content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

How would I go about setting the content size for a `scrollview`, when the content size is dynamic. I have added all my content to a `UIView` named "contentView", then try calling the `setcontentsize` as below, but this results in no scrolling.

sudo'ish code:

```
[scrollView setContentSize: contentView.frame.size];
```

Maybe "contentView" is not stretching its size to fit its children?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIView` or `UIScrollView` will not auto stretch based on content. You have to manually calculate the frames and position it accordingly inside the scrollview and then set the `contentSize` of the scrollview to the biggest possible size that can hold all its subviews.

Answer (score 1):

When you add stuff to your contentView call `[contentView sizeToFit]` and then the content view will stretch to fit its subviews, then, the code you post will work.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of content you are going to add dynamically. So let's say you have a big text data to show, then use the `UITextView` and as it is a subclass of the `UIScrollView`, you can get the setContentSize of TextView when you assign the text content. Based on that you can set the total size of the `UIScrollView`.

```
float yPoint = 0.0f;
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, yPoint, 320.0f, 400.0f)];

UITextView *calculatorTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
  calculatorTextView.text = @"My looong content text ..... this has a dynamic content";
[calculatorTextView sizeToFit];

yPoint = yPoint + calculatorTextView.contentSize.height; // Bingo, we have the new yPoiny now to start the next component.
```

// Now you know the height of your text and where it will end. So you can create a Label or another TextView and display your text there. You can add those components as subview to the scrollview.

```
UITextView *myDisplayContent = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, yPoint, 300.f, calculatorTextView.contentSize.height)];

myDisplayContent.text = @"My lengthy text ....";
[myScrollView addSubview:myDisplayContent];
```

// At the end, set the content size of the 'myScrollView' to the total length of the display area.

```
[myScrollView setContentSize:yPoint + heightOfLastComponent];
```

This works for me.